# Choosing elasticsearch index dynamically python

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

How can I choose an index dynamically using python.  My current code is as follows:

```
import os
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import shutil
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from esindex import createIndex
client=Elasticsearch()
```

I have 1000's of images and the name of the image would be:  1559624525_cb704087042c76bf.jpg.  I am splitting the name into two parts, timestamp (1559624525) and machid (cb704087042c76bf) and writing it into an es index.

```
path="/home/ubuntu/images/"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        try:        
            dat=name.split('_')[0]
            machid=name.split('_')[1]
            machid=machid.split('.')[0]
            createIndex(machid)  ##this creates index dynamically
            dat=int(dat)
            dat=datetime.utcfromtimestamp(dat).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
            dte=dat.split(' ')[0]
            id=id+1                 
            doc = {'sequence_id':id,'imagename': name, 'time_stamp': dat, 'date'=dte}
            #print(doc)
            client.index(index=machid,  body=doc)  ##this line is not working.  If i comment this out, shutil works.
            shutil.copy('/home/ubuntu/images/'+ name, '/home/ubuntu/test/')
            os.remove('/home/ubuntu/images/' + name)
        except Exception:
            continue
```

how can i input a document into elasticsearch by dynamically choosing the index.

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch?  You may be missing the `type` field of the `client.index()` function if you're running an Elasticsearch version earlier than 7.x.  Additionally, are you seeing any errors?  What does "not working" mean for you here?

Comment: @rusnyder i am using 7.0.1 where the type is deprecated... I am not getting error at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. print the Exception in except block
2. Check `machid` is not empty
3. Since there is not any errors use  Cat APIS to check any indeces created in your ES 
   curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/indices"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I figured that my code works.  In createIndex function I had a date field, which was set to date, however the above code parses the date as text.  To test, when I changed the date to text in createIndex, everything fell in place.  Replying this to complete the QA loop.